kable_styling overrides linesep = "" and adds space every 5 rows
This is partially related to this post, but for some reason I seem not to be able to fix my issue. In Quarto, when I create a table using kable with booktabs = TRUE and linesep = "" I get the expected results (no extra space every 5 rows):
---
title: "Test"
format: pdf
---

```{r}
library(kableExtra)
dat <- data.frame(v1 = letters[1:10], v2 = 1:10)
kable(dat, booktabs = TRUE, linesep = "")
```


If I use kable_styling() to get a striped table, an extra space is added after the fifth row:
---
title: "Test"
format: pdf
---

```{r}
library(kableExtra)
dat <- data.frame(v1 = letters[1:10], v2 = 1:10)
kable(dat, booktable = TRUE, linesep = "") |> 
  kable_styling(latex_options = "striped")
```


I get the extra space when I use kable_styling() even without booktabs = TRUE:
---
title: "Test"
format: pdf
---

```{r}
library(kableExtra)
dat <- data.frame(v1 = letters[1:10], v2 = 1:10)
kable(dat) |> 
  kable_styling()
```


To my understanding this is not the expected behavior of kable_styling(), is there something I am missing?

You are not missing something, the .tex processing seems to work different here. However, you could include a \setlength{\defaultaddspace}{0pt} in the header, this also makes the spaces go away.
---
title: "Test"
format: 
  pdf:
    include-in-header:
      text: |
        \setlength{\defaultaddspace}{0pt}
---

```{r}
library(kableExtra)
dat <- data.frame(v1 = letters[1:10], v2 = 1:10)
kable(dat) |> 
  kable_styling()
```


